# ¿Cómo validar una tabla temporal dentro de un loop?

Tags: mysql

Requiero hacer un insert Into dependiendo de si hay datos en una tabla temporal en mi procedimiento almacenado el problema está en que no puedo hacer selects multiples en una misma tabla temporal dentro de una misma función o procedimiento almacenado

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Persona_procedure`()
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT default FALSE;
   DECLARE Nombre varchar(100);
   DECLARE Identificacion varchar(100);       
   DECLARE cursor_sintomas cursor
   FOR select Nombre, Identificacion from personas;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Informe(
          Nombre varchar(100), 
          Identificacion varchar(100));
   open cursor_sintomas;
        loop1: loop
             FETCH cursor_sintomas INTO Nombre, cedula, cargo, Fecha, IdUsuario;
             IF done THEN
                LEAVE loop1;
             END IF;                 
             INSERT INTO Informe(Nombre, Identificacion) SELECT 
             (Nombre, Identificacion) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM 
             Informe s WHERE s.identificacion = identificacion);
         end loop;
   close cursor_sintomas;
   select * from Informe;
   Drop temporary table Informe; 
   END
```

Lo que realmente quiero realizar es que inserte registros cuando no existe datos dependiendo de la identificacion de la tabla temporal y la que se recorre en el FETCH, si ambas son iguales pues no debería guardar datos pero si no existe en la tabla

el problema está realmente que no puedo hacerle select mas de una vez dentro del mismo procedimiento a la tabla temporal Informe ¿Cómo puedo realizar la validación de esta tabla dentro del loop?

Comment: ¿Dónde se obtienen `cedula`, `cargo` y `Fecha` en `FETCH cursor_sintomas INTO...`? En `INSERT INTO Informe...`, ¿se insertará en `Informe` o se quiere insertar en `Informe_seg_sintomas`?.

Comment: @wchiquito Sí, los datos se insertarán en la tabla Informe. Ya pude realizar lo que quería de otra forma, simplemente el insert into no iba permitirme realizar lo que quería

Comment: Y no te parece correcto responder a tu pregunta explicando cómo lo lograste solucionar?? No solo los demás pueden responder tu pregunta... si tú mismo encuentras la respuesta antes que otra persona deberías responder para que cualquiera con un problema similar sea capaz de hacerlo también!

Comment: @Benito-B tienes total razón, compartiré mi solución para que demás personas pueda ver y opinar al respecto

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionar mi problema de la siguiente manera:

```
  IF NOT EXISTS(select Nombre from  Informes where s.Identificacion = Identificacion) THEN
        INSERT INTO Informes(Nombre, Identificacion) values (Nombre, Identificacion);
  END IF;
```

Solo cambie la manera en como quería yo insertar los datos dependiendo de qde una condicion donde antes utilizaba esta condición dentro del mismo INSERT

> INSERT INTO Informe(Nombre, Identificacion) SELECT
> (Nombre, Identificacion) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM
> Informe s WHERE s.identificacion = identificacion);

Dentro de los INSERT hacía dos consultas a la misma tabla lo cual no iba a permitir que esta tabla abriera 2 veces, el problema a principio no era tanto del loop pensando en que realmente por hacer un select dentro de un loop tendría problemas por consultar la misma tabla una y otra vez. Lo que realmente sucedía era que hacía la misma consulta 2 veces en un insert